# dbWriteTable to mysql with default and null as specified for each field

Tags: mysql, r, dbi, rmysql

I am trying to write a table from R to mySQL using dbWriteTable. I would also like to specify that the certain fieldtypes cannot be null and a default value for those specific fieldtypes.

I am currently using the below code to specify the field type but not sure how to specify a default and mark certain fields as cannot be null.

I am trying to preserve the structure of the table as I read it in R. While writing back to sql some elements of the structure are lost.

```
dbWriteTable(conn = connection, 
         name = "barcode_details", 
         value = barcode_details_update, 
         field.types = c(
           id = "float",
           order_no = "varchar(50)"))
```

Comment: Can you build the table using raw SQL? With that it's fairly easy to specify the default values and `NOT NULL`.

Comment: The table is already existing. Would it be better to truncate the table and append rows instead of ovrewriting the table? That way the primary keys are also preserved.

Comment: I the table already exists, then you can either drop the table and recreate it (if empty and/or disposable), or `ALTER TABLE` (more SQL language to add/change columns).